# Getting sale price issue of the product in multistore using collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am getting the few product IDs collection using the code

```
$collection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addIdFilter($product_ids)->setStore($this->_storeModelStoreManagerInterface->getStore())->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToSelect($this->getUsedMagentoAttributes())->setStoreId($this->_storeModelStoreManagerInterface->getStore()->getId());
```

And for getting the start price of configurable product, I am using the code as

```
$parent->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount() ->getValue(\Magento\Tax\Pricing\Adjustment::ADJUSTMENT_CODE);
```

This works when there is only one store.

But If I put the above price getting code in the multi-website loop while using the collection, I am not able to get the right prices for all the stores.

Comment: FYI - this code works in 2.0 but not in 2.1